# Zend Framework: how to order decorators correct?

Tags: html, zend-framework, label, decorator

I would like to make like this one:

```
<div><input type="checkbox" /> <label>Check this</label></div>
```

But not like this:

```
<div><label>Check this</label><input type="checkbox" /></div>
```

I tried to do this:

```
$stayInSystem->addDecorators(array(
                  'ViewHelper',
                  array('Label'),
                  array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div',)),
      ))->setLabel('Check this');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happened when you tried to do that?

Comment: And try replacing `addDecorators` into `setDecorators`.

Comment: So, I fixed this.
Just added:
array('Label', array('placement' => 'append')).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of Decorator for Label is set by "$_placement", in Zend_Form_Decorator_Label.
You can create a derivation of this class and set:

```
protected $_placement = 'APPEND';
```

In other way, it's possible to pass the "array('placement'=>'APPEND')" in the addDecorator, like this:

```
$stayInSystem->addDecorators(array(
              'ViewHelper',
              array('Label', array('placement'=>'APPEND')),
              array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div',)),
))->setLabel('Check this');
```

Hope It's help you...

Aka.